# Jquery: Click slideUp Issue

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have a JQuery navigation which on clicking a parent `<li>` slides down using JQuery. On a second click it will slide the navigation up. The problem I have is that my clients wants it also to slide back up if he clicks somewhere else on screen, i.e just clicking on blank white space would collapse the nav.

Any ideas?

Here is the Jquery:

```
$('#menu-flag-menu > li > a').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();});


$("#menu-flag-menu li a").click(function(){ 

    // close all opened sub menus
    $("ul", $(this).parent().siblings()).stop(true,true).slideUp();

    var ul = $(this).next("ul");     
    ul.stop(true,true).slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {

    // if we click on anything other than the navigation menu
    // or it's descendants then slide up the menu
    if(e.target.id !== "menu-flag-menu" 
        && !$(e.target).closest("#menu-flag-menu").length) {
        $(".sub-menu").stop().slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, this works apart from that once it collapses it hides the navigation completely.

Comment: Oops, forgot to specify the li's within the UL. Fixed :) .

Comment: This does the same unfortunately. It also makes the navigation disappear if I click anywhere on the screen regardless of whether the navigation is open.

Comment: It's hard to know what's going wrong without seeing it in action. Could you create a demo at jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: http://www.powerlase-photonics.com/ Its the navigation half way down starting with 'DPSS 1064nm'

Comment: Thanks, got it. Updated my answer. You just need to slide up the submenu elements.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Still not working. It is now not doing anything when clicking outside. I have it all within a document ready function and have placed your code underneath my code.

Comment: Perhaps because I used `.submenu` when in your code it is `.sub-menu` (with a hyphen). I updated my answer, it *should* work now.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to try using the .mouseenter event to open the menu and the mouseleave event to close the menu.